# Independence of integer sequences arising from Dirichlet's pigeonhole

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Dirichlet's pigeonhole says given sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb Z$ and a prime $p$ there is an integer $t$ coprime to $p$ with $\|r_i\|\in[-p^{(n-1)/n},p^{(n-1)/n}]$ at every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ where $r_i=ta_i\bmod p$.

What conditions on $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ gives such $t$ so that $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is independent of $(r_1,\dots,r_n)$ over $\mathbb R$?

Assume trivialities such as $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are pairwise coprime and close enough in size to $p$.

Comment: If $g=\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, it's certainly a necessary condition that $\max\{|a_1|,\dots,|a_n|\} \ge gp^{(n-1)/n}$ (if not, take $t\equiv g^{-1}\pmod p$. But that's certainly not sufficient, as we can let the $a_j$ be any numbers with either $|a_j| \le p^{(n-1)/n}/2$ or $|a_j - p/2| \le p^{(n-1)/n}/2$, including for example $a_1=1$, and take $t=2$.

Comment: @GregMartin $t\equiv g^{-1}(\bmod p)$ still does not guarantee linear independence.